# Debugging a local mobile site

Tags: mobile, web

I'm developing a mobile site for Android and iOS and I would like to see how it looks in Android Emulator and the iOS equivalent. My site is still only local, so I can't simply deploy it and go to phone's browser. I am using WAMP. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PhoneGap and deploy your HTML files within it to see how it looks.  Although it would not have the url bar on top like a mobile web browser but it gives you a good idea of things like performance and all the quirks you get with your mobile device.

Here is the Getting started guild from PhoneGap.

http://phonegap.com/developer/

Comment: Not sure about WAMP but you may be able to access the test site from the IP address of your WAMP computer on you mobile devices if they are all connected on the same local area network?